# WPF: DataGridRow IsMouseOver True trigger should set background on complete row and disable backgrounds set on individual cells temporarily

Tags: wpf

I use DataGridTextColumns which set the background of cells using an IValueConverter. Next to these I have

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The backgrounds set on the individual columns take precedence on the background set on the row on MouseOver.

How can I make sure the cell backgrounds are disabled temporarily if the mouse hovers over the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you set the value for the background manually. If that is the case that value takes precedence as you already noticed.

Instead you have to bring the "default" values you want to set into the style as setters as well and then overwrite them inside your trigger like you already do.

Without more code I can't give you a better explanation, but this will get you onto the right track.

Here is a rough example:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.

If you're using MVVM, you could use an AttachedBehavior to set a flag in your object on mouse over, that you could reference in your columns to shut off their color.

Here's an example behavior from https://znite.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/mvvm-mouseover-binding/

```
public static partial class Behaviours
{
  private static readonly List<FrameworkElement> _wiredUpElements = new List<FrameworkElement>();
  private static readonly object _wiredUpElementsLock = new object();

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverProperty
    = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MouseOver",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(Behaviours),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
            MouseOverBindingPropertyChanged));

  public static void SetMouseOver(FrameworkElement element, object value)
  {
    element.SetValue(MouseOverProperty, value);
  }

  private static void MouseOverBindingPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var element = d as FrameworkElement;
    if (element == null || _wiredUpElements.Contains(element))
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (_wiredUpElementsLock)
    {
        if (_wiredUpElements.Contains(element))
        {
            return;
        }
        _wiredUpElements.Add(element);
          element.MouseEnter += (sender, args) =>
                              {
                                  var e = (FrameworkElement) sender;
                                  SetMouseOver(e, e.DataContext);
                              };
    }
  }
}
```